# Spring data - modifying query concurrency

Tags: java, mysql, spring, concurrency, spring-data

I have the following repository:

```
public interface PlayerRealBalanceRepository extends JpaRepository<PlayerRealBalance, Long> {

   @Modifying
   @Query("update PlayerRealBalance balance set balance.balance = (balance.balance + ?1) where balance.id = ?2")
   public void increaseBalance(long amount, long balanceId);
}
```

My Question - is this query thread safe? what if 2 concurrent queries like this are executed exactly at the same time? Do i have to use a lock method in order for it to work properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will run into ACID(Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) problem. Hence better to use transaction please refer spring transaction management [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) For your reference here is the log(self explanatory) what happens if you implement transaction management(though I use Mybatis)

```
2014-02-11 16:48:21,008 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Switching JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin] to manual commit
2014-02-11 16:48:21,013 [main] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Creating a new SqlSession
2014-02-11 16:48:21,021 [main] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@16a23cf]
2014-02-11 16:48:21,091 [main] DEBUG o.m.s.t.SpringManagedTransaction - JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:] will be managed by Spring

// does the db operation


2014-02-11 16:48:21,792 [main] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@16a23cf]
2014-02-11 16:48:21,792 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
2014-02-11 16:48:21,792 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:]
2014-02-11 16:48:21,792 [main] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization committing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@16a23cf]
2014-02-11 16:48:21,792 [main] DEBUG org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils - Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@16a23cf]
2014-02-11 16:48:21,792 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Resetting isolation level of JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:] to 2
2014-02-11 16:48:21,792 [main] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@] after transaction
2014-02-11 16:48:21,792 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

Comment: If i'm using @Transactional annotation on my service it will be thread safe?

Comment: @Urbankleg Yes  will be